# Groovy best/recommended approach to ensure correct argument type

Tags: java, groovy, method-signature

I'm trying to do things in the best "Groovy-way" possible.
What's the best way to check the type of an argument (regarding performance and the "Groovy-way)? I have 2 implementations in mind:

```java
def deploy(json) {
    if (!(json instanceof String) && (json instanceof File)) {
        json = json.text
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException('argument type mismatch – \'json\' should be String or File')
    }
    // TODO
}
```

or

```
def deploy(File json) {
    deploy(json.text)
}

def deploy(String json) {
    // TODO
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The second one. If your method has to take a type, declare the type. If it returns a type, declare that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing groovy specific in your question, it's more about compile/runtime failures.

In first snippet `json` variable has `Object` type and allows everything to be passed in. It will fail in runtime if you pass in `JSON` object or `Map` by mistake.

In second snippet json is restricted to be either `File` or `String`. I like it more.

Comment: I also prefer the second option – is more close to Java, which I'm more comfortable with. In this case is probably better to go with Java than Groovy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` checks should be fine. However I think your condition is wrong -- it seems you want to do:

```
if (json instanceof File) {
    json = json.text
} else if(!(json instanceof String)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException('argument type mismatch – \'json\' should be String or File')
}
```

You can also write the following:

```
if (json.class in [String.class, File.class]) {
```

Your second approach looks simpler with just two methods that clearly show the intent through their signatures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I think my logic is correct, because I'm expecting a String, So, if `json` is one, the type is correct. 
Besides that, thanks for the `.class in [...]`.

Comment: @Matheus The condition would cause an `IllegalArgumentException` if `json` were a `String`.